# Are my hash ids protected from decryption?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Javascript version of a thing called hashids, hashids.js which can be found here:http://www.hashids.org/

basic usage

To encrypt a simple number:

```
var Hashids = new Hashids();
var hash = Hashids.encrypt(123);

var Hashids = new Hashids();
var numbers = Hashids.decrypt('Mj3');
```

Here's my issue:

using custom salt

Hashids supports personalizing your hashes by accepting a salt value. If you don't want others to decrypt your hashes, provide a unique string to the constructor.

```
var Hashids = new Hashids('this is my salt 1');
var hash = Hashids.encrypt(123); /* hash is now "nVB" */
```

Couldn't someone just look at the source and view my custom salt? How is this protection from decryption? am I missing something?

Comment: You can't trust anything that happens at the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously not a hash, as hashes, by definition, cannot be decrypted. (They can be cracked, but that's a different matter) If this is just a fun little Javascript app that you're making, you should be fine with hashid.js. If it's anything larger than a fun little project, use a real hash. `MD5`, `SHA-1`, etc. Here's a good Javascript hash library: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

EDIT: Since people could see your client's code anyways, you should use PHP to output the pre-hashed variable, so nobody can see what it was originally.

Comment: MD5 is so easy to decrypt these days. `SHA-1` is a better hash.

Comment: Also, I want to add that my usage would be for URL shortening. I only worry about collisions. Do you think that is a possibility with hashids.js?

Comment: Collisions can and will happen with any type of hash. There are an infinite combination of characters but only a limited amount of hash outputs. You should make a database of these shortened hashes and ensure that there isn't an existing value in there before you upload it to the server.

Comment: Do you think adding a username, like a facebook or twitter username that was used to login, before the forward slash hash id, like username/AdAX3 would make the chances even slimmer?

Comment: Definitely. The chances of a random collision occurring when isolated like that is very small. Presuming each user only creates around 5 hashes, there is almost a 0% chance of collisions. What is your backend being written in? I may be able to help you with the database aspect if you choose to take that path.

Comment: I'm actually using a Baas for backend, Parse. "If each user creates around 5 hashes"? Many users might create many posts which will provide a URL with the unique characters generated which I'm calling hashes. Just like when a user saves code on jsfiddle and a url with unique characters can be used to visit that code again or to share. If users go beyond 5, they're at risk of collision?

Comment: No, 5 was an arbitrary number. Sorry for the confusion. Also, if you're going to be trimming the string size to around 10 characters, then the type of hash doesn't matter (as long as it goes over 10 characters, for instance), and you may want to use a quicker hash, like an md5. Your probability of a collision is `1 / (36 ^ length)`, so even a 5 character hash would be pretty unlikely to collide.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot. You've been very helpful. What is your skillset btw?

Comment: I was taught Java at school, and I taught myself Javascript, jQuery, Node.JS, and Meteor on my own. Meteor is a super awesome Node.JS based framework, and I suggest you look into it. But yeah, no problem. Glad to help.

Comment: Cool dude, well if you don't mind, I'd like to talk with you sometime. I visited your website. I have your info. You seem like you may be someone I'd enjoy talking to.